# Problem in MyEclipse "Processing Dirty Regions"

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

Is there anyone who have encountered "Processing Dirty Regions" error in MyEclipse? Actually everytime i press a key in JSP it shows a popup, which says

*An internal error occurred during: "Processing Dirty Regions".
org/eclipse/wst/sse/ui/internal/reconcile/validator/ValidationHelper*

By googling i found that [i have to rename a jar](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=90032) , i did that but what it does is, it will open the JSP in notepad or any other system editor [ now it will not open in MyEclipse]. So this solution is discarded.

Please let me know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting MyEclipse Configurations to earlier version solved this problem.

*Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration*

Select 'Revert to previous' now select the configuration you think, was not having the problem.